# Datetime value is assign to as expected while converting from string to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to convert string to datetime format using DateTime.TryParseExact. Birthday is remains unchanged when go to in controller code.

```
 public string FormattedBirthday
 {
     get
     {
         if (Birthday == null) return "";

         return Birthday?.ToString("d");
     }
     set
     {
         CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
         if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "d", enUS, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out DateTime parsedDate))
         {
             this.Birthday = parsedDate;
         }
     }
 }
```

There is FormattedBirthday is string format ("MM/dd/yyyy") and Birthday is datetime.
"formattedBirthday": "01/12/2024",
"formattedDeathday": "01/12/2024",

Comment: -"I'm trying to convert string to datetime format"_ DateTime doesn't have a format, that's for strings. Also, converting string to DateTime is called parsing.

Comment: Please provide us a [mcve] that we could use to replicate your issue. Is there anything else that could also be updating `Birthday`?

Comment: DateTime has no format, it's a binary value. Formats apply only when formatting into strings for display or parsing strings into DateTime values. *DON'T* use string properties to store dates if possible. If you absolutely have to, don't use localized formats. Use the unambiguous ISO8601 format instead (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss....)

Comment: In any case what's the question? If the current culture is `en-US` you'll get back a *string* in the US format. Where does `"formattedBirthday": "01/12/2024", "formattedDeathday": "01/12/2024",` come from? That looks like an attempt to serialize the string properties into JSON. The string values were serialized without any modification. They're useless as date values though. The standard format for dates in JSON is ISO8601. All JSON serializers use that format for `DateTime` properties